# How do I convert a spreadsheet read with OpenPyXL into XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, data-science, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

## TL; DR

How do I load a spreadsheet template using OpenPyXL

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('template.xlsx')
```

then create a new one and fill the rows data with XlsxWriter?

```
xls_workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('proposal.xlsx')

# Missing step
xls_workbook = workbook.add_worksheet(workbook)
xls_workbook.write(CELL_COST, cost)
```

## Details

I have a spreadsheet with several tabs with a quite complex formatting (used as a sales proposal), so there is a lot of formatting that must be preserved.

So, instead of programatically create the spreadsheet, I have to:

1. Open the template for reading using OpenPyXL
2. Extract the template and save it into a `template.py` file
3. Create the sales pitch spreadsheets using the template, creating new tables with XlsxWriter.

Is there a simple way of extracting the template or do really I need recreate the whole layout programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same "problem" and have not found much about it. So finally I code a little function to copy the template sheet and some styling.

It's 2 years late but I hope it helps someone who comes to this question.

```
def openpyxl_to_xlsxwriter(openpyxl_workbook, xlsxwriter_workbook):
    template_sheets = openpyxl_workbook.get_sheet_names()
    # Copy all the sheets from the openpyxl template to the xlsxwriter workbook.
    for sheet_name in template_sheets:
        xlsxwriter_workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

    for sheet in template_sheets:
        openpyxl_active_sheet = openpyxl_workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
        xlsxwriter_active_sheet = xlsxwriter_workbook.get_worksheet_by_name(sheet)
        for row in openpyxl_active_sheet.rows:
            for cell in row:

                # # Copy some STYLES # #

                # Copy font color and Background color
                cell_style = {}
                theme = cell.fill.start_color.theme
                tint = cell.fill.start_color.tint
                font_theme = cell.font.color.theme
                font_tint = cell.font.color.tint

                font_color = theme_and_tint_to_rgb(openpyxl_workbook, font_theme, font_tint)
                cell_style['font_color'] = font_color
                try:
                    background_color = theme_and_tint_to_rgb(openpyxl_workbook, theme, tint)
                    cell_style['bg_color'] = background_color
                except:
                    pass
                cell_format = xlsxwriter_workbook.add_format(cell_style)

                # Copy border

                border_left = cell.border.left.border_style
                border_right = cell.border.right.border_style
                border_top = cell.border.top.border_style
                border_bottom = cell.border.bottom.border_style

                if border_left:
                    cell_format.set_left()
                if border_right:
                    cell_format.set_right()
                if border_top:
                    cell_format.set_top()
                if border_bottom:
                    cell_format.set_bottom()

                # Copy Cell Width and Height

                cell_height = openpyxl_active_sheet.row_dimensions[cell.row].height
                cell_width = openpyxl_active_sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].width

                column_index = cell.column - 1
                xlsxwriter_active_sheet.set_column(column_index, column_index, cell_width)

                row_index = cell.row - 1
                xlsxwriter_active_sheet.set_row(row_index, cell_height)

                # Copy Cell Value
                xlsxwriter_active_sheet.write(cell.coordinate, cell.value, cell_format)
```